Intermittent scrambled keyboard mapping in browsers including Chrome and Firefox on Ubuntu 22.04
I found a strange bug with Chrome, where half the time when I enter a site and start typing in a text-box, all my keymaps would be scrambled. Most keys on the keyboard map to something completely random like page down, scroll to bottom, or tab, but a few of the keys still work normally, like w and f.
This strange behaviour seems to toggle off when I double-click tab. Also, double-clicking tab again seems to turn it back on. I've tried removing all Chrome extensions, moving to a clean profile, and moving to Firefox, but the issue seems to persist.
I thought it was an issue with Chromium but found that I also get this bug on Firefox, which is not Chromium-based whereas I don't get this issue on VSCode, which is Chromium-based. I've also found that this does not occur in Obsidian, so it's likely not a system-level keybind. Is there some underlying package shared by Chrome and Firefox but not VSCode and Obsidian?
OS: Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS x86_64
Host: Laptop 16 (AMD Ryzen 7040 Series) A
DE: GNOME 42.9
Kernel: 6.5.0-1023-oem


For me and some people on Reddit it was caused by a screen reader being switched on somehow. Look for the little man in the top bar and switch it off there.
